# Method Not Allowed (405) The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, http-status-code-405

I got 405 error after trying to submit in my HTML code from my Flask app to try to predict Car Price. I think the error comes from the Flask app file but I did not found such wrong code

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle as pk
from os.path import dirname, join

current_dir = dirname(__file__)
file_path = join(current_dir, "./static/Cleaned Car Dataset.csv")
app = Flask(__name__)
model = pk.load(open('LinearRegression.pkl', 'rb'))
car = pd.read_csv(file_path)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    companies = sorted(car['company'].unique())
    car_models = sorted(car['name'].unique())
    years = sorted(car['year'].unique(), reverse=True)
    fuel_types = car['fuel_type'].unique()

    return render_template('index.html', companies=companies, car_models=car_models, years=years, fuel_types=fuel_types)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        company = request.form.get('company')
        car_model = request.form.get('model')
        year = request.form.get('year')
        fuel_type = request.form.get('fuel_type')
        company.insert(0, "Select Company")
        kms_driven = request.form.get('kilo_driven')
        print(company, car_model, year, fuel_type, kms_driven)

        prediction = model.predict(pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'company', 'year', 'kms_driven', 'fuel_type'], data=np.array([car_model, company, year, year, kms_driven, fuel_type]).reshape(1, 5)))

        print(prediction)

        return str(np.round(prediction[0], 2))
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: what *method* (and path) is used by the client? also, what `Allow` headers are being sent in the response to the client?

Comment: Your code looks right which makes me think that it might have something to do with your index.html file and the form handling. Share the code to that as well.

Comment: I put it in this pastebin link, https://pastebin.com/wxQnghLY